# Why is it returning undefined for the month. JS date

Tags: javascript, html, date, undefined

```
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth();
var arr = [
   'лютого',
   'березня',
   'квітня',
   'травня',
   'червня',
   'липня',
   'серпня',
   'вересня',
   'жовтня',
   'листопада',
   'грудня',
   'січня',
];

$('.rf_title').text('Данi оновлено ' + date.getDate() + ' ' + arr[month-1] + ' ' + date.getFullYear() +' о ' + (date.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours()) + ':' + '' + (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes()));
```

I’m confused as to why this is showing undefined. It worked fine up until New Years. As soon as 2022 hit it’s done for.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykWnG.jpg)

Comment: getMonth() returns the zero-index month. No need to -1

Comment: `date.getMonth()` will give you 0 to 11. The rest I'm sure you can deduce.

Comment: You could use `... + arr[(month? month : arr.length) - 1] + ...` so that if *month* is zero (January), the expression returns the value for December.

Comment: Note that the language code for Ukrainian is uk-UA so you can get the month name as `new Date().toLocaleString('uk-UA',{month:'long'})` (currently "січень") and save some trouble. :-)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps you:)

Answer (score 1):

Month is 0-index, so remove the `-1` in `month-1` will work (if you move January to the beginning of the array).

Since now in January, it will use `-1` which is incorrect.

> The getMonth() method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year).

Correct way to do that:

```js
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth();
var arr = [
   'січня',
   'лютого',
   'березня',
   'квітня',
   'травня',
   'червня',
   'липня',
   'серпня',
   'вересня',
   'жовтня',
   'листопада',
   'грудня',
];
console.log(arr[month])
$('.rf_title').text('Данi оновлено ' + date.getDate() + ' ' + arr[month] + ' ' + date.getFullYear() +' о ' + (date.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours()) + ':' + '' + (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The OP wants to get the previous month name, so your answer should tell them how to do that (e.g. `arr[(month || arr.length) - 1]`). :-)

Comment: @RobG, i think the OP ask for `I’m confused as to why this is showing undefined.`, so I mainly explain it. Also, the code snippet below does show the correct way. I don't think my answer is off-topic, but anyways, I will update that the below one is correct wat.

Comment: @RobG No, they want the current month. They complained about the code breaking in January after it worked fine in the previous months. They currently have an array starting with Feburary and ending with January, so it already works correctly for all months except January.

Comment: The original code `arr[month-1]` shows the previous month and "*worked fine up until New Years*", so reasonable to expect that the previous month is what was required. Otherwise it would not have "worked fine", given "січня" is Ukrainian for January.

Comment: @RobG, I agree with you and doesn't notice that in the question, but I think that is caused by OP doesn't really month is 0-index, so that is why my answer mainly focus on that.:)

Comment: Maybe, however the OP seems to have lost interest so zero chance it will be cleared up. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The `getMonth()` method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year). So now in January it return 0. And `arr[month-1]` would be `arr[-1]` which is undefined.